# Graphics glitch affecting entire Blender window

Tags: interface, windows

I may have encountered a bug in Blender: it shows green dots and other random colors all over the interface, and if I move the mouse pointer the colors change!

Here's a picture of how the screen looks:
[image: blender screen]

Comment: try File->User Preferences->System 

Set Window Draw Method to Triple Buffer.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue for me:

from *File > User Preferences > System*, set "Window Draw Method" to *Full*

Comment: that slove not work for me!
but thanks!